# Diferent Button Text Font in Debug and Release in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

i am developing a Vuejs web app using Vuetify, but the button layout is working fine in debug server, but when i build app for release and put in Nginx server the button text font change.

Debug server button
[image: Debug server button]

Release server button
[image: Release server button]

And i using default v-btn from Vuetify

```
<v-btn class="col-5"
     @click="mMad.serial_interface? serialInterfaceDialog=mMad.serial_interface 
     :serialInterfaceDialog=true">
                    {{mMad.serial_interface? 'Editar' :'Cadastrar'}}
</v-btn>
<v-btn class="col-5" color="red" @click="deleteSerialDialog = mMad.serial_interface"
     v-if="mMad.serial_interface">
       Excluir
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Doublecheck if the css stylesheets are loaded properly on the release server?

Comment: Yep, worked now, my bad, i have used i old css file in this project, for some reason this stylesheets  only appears in release, thanks